# sql - trying to select a column with datetime with a condition of date only

Tags: php, sql

so i have this table: http://prntscr.com/it53pm (in this link).

what im trying to do is select schedule where schedule date = current date.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the SQL query that you have tried so that people can help you progress further. Users usually get downvoted if questions look like they dont have research effort. Thanks!

Comment: Please tag the particular RDBMS (database type) you're using, and add the table into the question itself, including the types of the columns in the table, and show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard SQL:

```
select * from tab
where cast(schedule as date) = current_date
```

Longer syntax but allows indexed access:

```
select * from tab
where schedule >= cast(current_date as timestamp)
  and schedule <  cast(current_date + interval '1' day as timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NOW()` in your where clause

```
for example
SELECT *
WHERE schedule like NOW()
```

- NOW() will be "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS" at curent date and time

Comment: curdate() gives you the current Date, if you look at the screenshot you could see, that he also has the time in the column

Comment: ah ok i'll edit my answer

Comment: This will not work.

Comment: this will work but will never got the result isn'it?
i think yours is the right answer @dnoeth

Comment: you would have to to excecute this query at the very exact millisecond for it to work, because NOW() gives you the miliseconds aswell

Comment: Not returning the correct answer is *not working* for me :-)  It's exactly the same as `schedule = NOW()` but relies on automatic typecasts to do the string comparison and then needs much more CPU.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT aid,schedule
FROM yourtable
WHERE TRUNC(schedule)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)

This works in Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT aid FROM table WHERE schedule >= TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
```

Comment: And what about tasks scheduled for tomorrow?

Comment: aa60466 only requested about current date, so I thought the last data only today

Comment: Yes, but your WHERE currently includes scheduled tasks *after* today, too.